# Move to next fold of level 1 in vim

Tags: vim, code-folding

I am looking for a good way to jump between function definitions in C++ code. I like the idea of using folds for that, because I can move to the next function/method using `zj`, but that only works if there are no nested folds inside the functions (e.g., by setting `foldnestmax=1`).

Is there a way to tell vim to "move to the next fold of level 1", so that I can easily move to the next method?

Note: I know about `]m` and `[m` and it's not what I'm looking for. I would prefer a fold-based solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `set foldnestmax=1` temporarily, move to next fold and set the option back to its original value:

```
:nnoremap <silent> zj :let max = &fdn<bar>let &fdn = 1<CR>zj:let &fdn=max<CR>
:nnoremap <silent> zk :let max = &fdn<bar>let &fdn = 1<CR>zk:let &fdn=max<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can you zr and/or zm and moving through the remaining folds with zj and zk